# Shortcut to embedding picture link in MS-Word Doc

Tags: ms-word

I want to embed/link 90+ .jpg images in a MS-Word doc. I can do it the long way, Click Insert/Picture/From File, then pick the file from the dialog box, click Insert, click Link to File. It's

Is there a way to quickly add multiple dummy links, then go back and the names of the files in the link? That is, is there a viewing mode where I can see and edit the file names?
Is there a 3rd party tool that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the VBA macro recorder and build a loop around the generated code?

Comment: Not being very adept at VBA macros, I found a workaround in C#. I created one page in word with a picture link and dummy text. Then I replicated it 100 times. My C# program walks through the links and replaces the file name. Since my files are sequentialy numbered (Picture1.jpg, etc), it was easy to do it in a loop.